# Grouping items in RadJumplist according to Weekday

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik

I want to group and sort some items according to weekday . The week starts from Monday and so the first item in group  header should be Monday then Tuesday and so on.

BusData.Weekday is a string and holds value as WeekDay = "Monday".

Code below groups the items according to weekday but sorts them in alphabetical order so Friday is the first item in the group header.

```
GenericGroupDescriptor<BusData, string> group = new GenericGroupDescriptor<BusData, string>();
        group.SortMode = ListSortMode.Ascending;
        group.KeySelector = (key) =>
        {
            return key.WeekDay;
        };
GroupDescriptors.Add(group);
```

What should I change to get the desired result ?

Also can I bind other items in the group header like the text in the second textbox of the code below ?

```
<telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="12,0,12,0" FontSize="30" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Time}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

RadJumpList supports [SortDescriptors](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radjumplist-features-sort-descriptors.html) as well.

Just add a SortWeight to your BusData class

```
class BusData
{
    public int SortWeight
    {
        get
        {
            switch(this.WeekDay)
            {
                 case "Monday": return 0;                        
                 case "Tuesday": return 1;
                 // ... add more days here
            }
            return 7;
        }
    }
}
```

and then create and add a sort descriptor

```
var sorter = new GenericSortDescriptor<BusData, int>(
    b => b.SortWeight) { SortMode = ListSortMode.Ascending };
SortDescriptors.Add(sorter);
```

Rather then binding to a property, I prefer to do it in xaml

```
<telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupDescriptors>
    <data:PropertyGroupDescriptor PropertyName="WeekDay" SortMode="None" />
</telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.GroupDescriptors>

<telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.SortDescriptors>
    <data:PropertyGroupDescriptor PropertyName="SortWeight" SortMode="Ascending" />
</telerikDataControls:RadJumpList.SortDescriptors>
```

the really **important** thing to remember is to set the `SortMode` of the group descriptor to `None`, because if you not set it it will be set to ascending and this will overwrite the sort descriptor behaviour.